# Slow performance while setting some rows in bold in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make some row in bold in a datagridview. This is applied when the binding of the datagridview is complete.

```
Font bold = new System.Drawing.Font(this.GridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.GridView.Rows)
{
    FlattenedResult item = row.DataBoundItem as FlattenedResult;
    if(item != null)
    {
        if(item.ParentID.Equals(item.ID))
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = bold;
         }
     }
 }
```

The issue is that this operation takes more than 9 minutes (only for 1000 rows...). Is there a better way ?

Thanks !

Comment: You should look into Virtual Mode.

Comment: Instead of looping through datagridview, try select index of row you want to make bold from datagridview datasource using datatable.select, then use that index to set bold

Comment: first filter the parent rows and itrate only parent rows to set style

Answer (score 2):

I used to do same thing as you, for 10 rows it took 0.050 sec to complete.

According to [Cell Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/1yef90x0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), row/cell `Style` properties are instantiating a new `DataGridViewCellStyle` each time you call the getter (what you do to be able to set the `Font` property).

Creating a new `DataGridViewCellStyle` only once raises performances ten times for me. With the following piece of code, it took 0.005 sec to complete.

```
private void dataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle(this.DataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle);
    style.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(this.DataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridView.Rows)
    {
        FlattenedResult item = row.DataBoundItem as FlattenedResult;

        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.ParentID.Equals(item.ID))
                row.DefaultCellStyle = style;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also filter `DataBindingComplete` type with `e.ListChangedType` property.

It may not be the better solution but I hope it will help to find it.

You can also take a look at shared rows but it seems to work well only with user-interactionless  DataGridViews.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be caused by your grid properties. In my case I had set property to

```
AutoSizeColumnsMode=AllCells
```

Probably after cell formatting all other cells in column and header cell had to be redrawn to fit theirs dimensions to the new cell dimensions. After I was changed property value to it default value `"None"`, grid is painted immediately.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use virtual mode `dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true`, as suggested Aphelion. You can see example here [DataGridView live display of datatable using virtual mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717243/datagridview-live-display-of-datatable-using-virtual-mode)

2) Prepare your data source rows with property ShouldBeInBold (find meaningfull name).
And use it in `CellValueNeeded` event subscriber.