# Paging my Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, paging

I have a DataTable.
I want view only 10 rows and when I click "next" or "previous" I want to get the relevant next/previous rows (10 or what ever number of rows there is in block).

BTW I'm using C#

Answer (score 0):

Paging is based off sorting. Consider a `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId > 0;
```

That would return you the first 10 customers in the table. Now, when you want the next page you would need to build a statement like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId > @CustomerId
```

and provide a value to `@CustomerId`. That value would be the `CustomerId` of the last displayed row.

Comment: I don't want to connect database... Work only with datatable

Comment: @Itsik, um, how do you plan on filling the `DataTable`? You don't want to pull back a `DataTable` into memory and then try and page that - it would be the wrong approach. Every time you need a page, then go get one, because if the user **resorts** the data the query would have to change, thus invalidating the `DataTable` cache. If the user were to sort by `CustomerName` it would then be `WHERE CustomerName > @CustomerName` for the next page for example.

Comment: I'm filling the datatable from web service

Comment: @Itsik, okay. So if you're dead set against doing this way then bind an `ObjectDataSource` to the `DataTable` and then simply set that up for paging.

Comment: Do you mean grid view ?

Comment: @Itsik, the `GridView` binds to the `ObjectDataSource` but doesn't contain the paging functionality. Maybe I'm wrong, but from memory that's how I setup a custom `ObjectDataSource` a while back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with virtual mode on the U.I control [DataGridView live display of datatable using virtual mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717243/datagridview-live-display-of-datatable-using-virtual-mode)

What database your using should impact the SQL your using. (i.e ref cursors being returned is best for oracle)